# EditText directly to TextView

Tags: android, textview, android-edittext

I did some research but I couldn't find the answer to my question. I have a `EditText` and a `TextView` in my layout. What I would like to accomplish is that when I type in the `EditText`, it goes directly into my `TextView`. I don't know if this is possible. Someone who can help me solve my problem?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: What do you want to say?

Comment: That when i type in the edittext, the text directly goes to the textview in the same layout.

Comment: Implement a `onTextChanged` listener for the edittext and in that set the text in the textview

Comment: Thanks, will try this. I think this will do the job! :)

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have to implement a `TextWatcher` in your `onCreate` method for the `Activity`.

```
EditText editBox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_box_id);
editBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s){
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview_id)).setText(s.toString());
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
});
```

Be sure to swap `R.id.edit_box_id` with the actual `EditText` field's ID, and `R.id.textview_id` with the actual `TextView` id.

Comment: Thank you, will try both answers.

Answer (score 1):

Its too simple you have just implement ***addTextChangedListener*** method

```
uredit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s){
       urtextview.setText(s.toString());
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya! It's possible use edit text on change listener so while on change method you can set text to your text view.

```
Field2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int count, int after) {
   }

   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int before, int count) {
     Field1.setText("");
   }
  });
```